# How to Select Different Sum values from same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

**users**

```
userid name surname active
```

**activities**

```
userid activity type
```

There are 3 types of activity.

I want to select total activity numbers of all the users according to their types. The resultset should be displayed as the following:

```
userid name surname at1 at2 at3
```

at1 stands for total activity count of activity type 1 (same for at2 and at3).

I have tried to use that query but returns null.

```
SELECT u.userid, u.name, u.surname, 
       SUM( a1.activity ) AS at1,
       SUM( a2.activity ) AS at2, 
       SUM( a3.activity ) AS at3
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN activities AS a1 ON a1.userid = u.userid
INNER JOIN activities AS a2 ON a2.userid = u.userid
INNER JOIN activities AS a3 ON a3.userid = u.userid
WHERE u.active=1
      AND a1.type =1
      AND a2.type =2
      AND a3.type =3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this(this is pseudo code):

```
select u.name, (SELECT sum(a1.activity) from activities a1 where a1.type=1 and
a1.userid=u.userid) as at1, (SELECT sum(a2.activity) from activities a2 where a2.type=2 and
a2.userid=u.userid) as at2 FROM user AS u group by u.userid
```

Comment: After a few modification it works now for my intention. Activity column holds text, so it is impossible to get a sum value. It should be COUNT(a1.activity) not SUM(a1.activity) and for the others too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional sum as

```
select
u.userid, 
u.name, 
u.surname, 
sum(a.type = 1) as at1,
sum(a.type = 2) as at2,
sum(a.type = 3) as at3
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN activities AS a ON a.userid = u.userid
group by u.userid
```

Comment: this query sums activity type numbers which results wrong values.